# Java - Classe não mostra informação solicitada

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, postgresql, window-builder

Bom dia,

Estou precisando arrumar um problema quando solicito no "dao.Acessar" o get da Classe model.Usuário retorna vázio = null.

Quuando é chamado: doLogin(model.Acessar acessar) consigo vê a informação pelo JOptionPane agora quando faço o mesmo no: atualizarUsuario(model.Acessar acessar) não é exibido nada!

**Classe: model.Acessar**

```
public class Acessar {
```

// Variáveis
    private String nome;
    private String senha;
    private String grupo;
    private Date acesso;

```
// Getters & Setters
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}
public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}   
public String getGrupo() {
    return grupo;       
}
public void setGrupo(String grupo) {
    this.grupo = grupo;
}
public Date getAcesso() {
    return acesso;
}

public void setAcesso(Date date) {
    this.acesso = date;
}
```

// Construtores

```
// Usuário e Senha
public Acessar(String nome, String senha) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.senha = senha;
}

// Acesso
public Acessar(Date acesso) {
    this.acesso = acesso;
}
```

}

**Classe: dao.Acessar**

```
public class Acessar {

public static Connection con = dao.ConectarDB.getConexao();

public static String doLogin(model.Acessar acessar) {

    // Variáveis
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String sql = null; 
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ResultSet autenticacao = null;
    ResultSet grupo = null;
    sql = "select * from usuario where nome=? and senha=?";

    // Validar Usuário
    try {

        ps = ConectarDB.getConexao().prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, acessar.getNome());
        ps.setString(2, acessar.getSenha());
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        autenticacao = rs; 

        // Validar Grupo
        try {

            ps = null;
            sql = null;
            rs = null;
            sql = "select * from usuario where grupo=?";

            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql); 
            ps.setString(1, "Suporte");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            grupo = rs;

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }

        // Autenticação do Usuário
        if(autenticacao.next()) {

            // Grupo do Usuário
            if(grupo.next()) {

            } else {
                return null;
            }

            return "Suporte";

        } else {
            return "erro";
        }            

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "erro";
    }

}

// Atualizar Acesso do Usuário
public void atualizarUsuario(model.Acessar acessar) {

    // Variáveis
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String sql = "update usuario set acesso=? where nome=?";

    // Inserção
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setDate(1, new Date(acessar.getAcesso().getTime()));
        ps.setString(2, acessar.getNome());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nome: " + acessar.getNome()); // Mostra = null, por que?
        ps.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

**view.Acessar (jFrame)**

```
// Botão Ok
    btnOk = new JButton("Ok");
    btnOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                

        // Capturar Campos
            String nome = tfNome.getText();
            String senha = new String (pfSenha.getPassword());

        // Validar Usuário
            model.Acessar acessar = new model.Acessar(nome, senha);
            String autenticar = dao.Acessar.doLogin(acessar);

        // Validar Conexão com a Internet
            try {
                Socket socket = null;
                socket = new Socket("www.google.com.br", 80);
                socket.close();

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Computador sem acesso a Internet!", "Informação", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }

        // Validar Conexão com Banco de Dados PostGreSQL
            try {
                ConectarDB db = new ConectarDB();
                db.main(null);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


        // Autenticar Usuário
            if(autenticar != "erro") {

                // Capturar Data e Hora e Atualizar
                java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
                model.Acessar acessarM = new model.Acessar(date);

                // Atualizar Tabela do Usuário com Ultimo Acesso
                dao.Acessar uAtualizar = new dao.Acessar();
                uAtualizar.atualizarUsuario(acessarM);                  
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, acessarM.getAcesso(), "Informação", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);               

                // Abrir a Janela do Sistema
                if(autenticar == "Suporte") {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Você pertence ao Grupo de (Suporte)", "Informação", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    new Sistema().main(null);
                    dispose();
                }                   

            } else if (autenticar == "erro"){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nome ou senha inválidos, favor verificar.", "Informação", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Não estou entendendo sua pergunta. Aonde no DAO Acessar tem um get pra classe usuario? Não encontrei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
model.Acessar acessarM = new model.Acessar(date);
```

Vocês está instânciando o objeto novamente antes de atualizar, sem passar o nome e a senha, diferente da primeira chamada.

```
model.Acessar acessar = new model.Acessar(nome, senha);
```

---

Faça o seguinte:

Crie o construtor public Acessar(){} vazio na classe Acessar.

Ao invés de você fazer:

```
model.Acessar acessar = new model.Acessar(nome, senha);
```

Faça:

```
 model.Acessar acessar = new model.Acessar();

 acessar.setNome(nome);

 acessar.setSenha(senha);
```

Remova o trecho:

```
model.Acessar acessarM = new model.Acessar(date);
```

E substitua por:

```
acessar.setAcesso(date);
```

Comment: Me desculpe. Continuo sem entender kkkkk sou um tanto leigo... ainda

Comment: Complementei a explicação.